# Issue regarding the installation of android backend server

Tags: android, python, sql-server, backend

I have an issue regarding the android backend storage. Can anyone help in initial steps from determining which server to buy, how to use it and which integrated development environment (ide) should be used for python??
Any leads will be helpful. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check out once about Firebase
link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/
it may useful to you.it offers storage and realtime database and more.